# Is it possible to generate cucumber html reports with only scenario titles with out steps

Tags: cucumber

Is it possible to generate cucumber html reports with only scenario titles with out steps?

I am looking to generate html report by email,But i want the reports to be generated with all scenarios only with title, so that my report is not huge and easy to know which scenarios failed.

I am sure somebody may have solution for this.Can ony one please share this or give me idea how would i get it done.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

You would need to build a custom formatter. The [Cucumber Wiki](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber/wiki/Custom-Formatters) has some details on doing this.

To hide the steps, you can create a custom formatter that overrides the Html formatter's `before_step_result` and `build_step` methods.

If your support folder create an .rb file with:

```
require 'cucumber/formatter/html'

module Cucumber
  module Formatter
    class HtmlStepless < Html
      def before_step_result(step_result)
        #TODO: What is this used for?
        @step_match = step_result.step_match
        @hide_this_step = true
        if step_result.exception
          if @exceptions.include?(step_result.exception)
            @hide_this_step = true
            return
          end
          @exceptions << step_result.exception
        end
        if step_result.status != :failed && @in_background ^ step_result.background
          @hide_this_step = true
          return
        end
        @status = step_result.status
        return if @hide_this_step
        set_scenario_color(step_result.status)
        @builder << "<li id='#{@step_id}' class='step #{step_result.status}'>"
      end

      def build_step(keyword, step_match, status)
        # Do nothing
      end

    end
  end
end
```

When you run Cucumber, tell it to use the custom formatter:

```
cucumber -f Cucumber::Formatter::HtmlStepless -o output.htm
```